# MVCScaffolding and AutoMapper Mapped ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, automapper, t4, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

Does anyone know if there are Scaffolding templates etc for MVCScaffolding that create ViewModels per view and adds AutoMapper mapping for them? I want to follow Jimmy Boggards recommendation that every view should have a dedicated ViewModel and it would be good if I could automate that process.

Even if it used all the fields of the entity as the ViewModel that would be a good start. If not has anyone done anything similar I see [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/03/28/scaffolding-actions-and-unit-tests-with-mvcscaffolding/) it is creating a ViewModel by default. So I wondered if anyone had taken that further?